# Xamarin forms sync framework aspnetcore restful api

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have spent the last several  days searching for suitable sync framework for xamarin.forms or plan and simple sqlite to sql server, or really anything.

I found this but it is 3+ years old and the packages are not apsnetcore ready.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync

which is interesting since it appears the client is on the lastest version
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data

A custom sync approach
https://xamarinhelp.com/mobile-database-bi-directional-synchronization-rest-api/

and lastly this 
https://winstongubantes.blogspot.com/2018/09/synchronizing-offline-data-with-matcha.html

I know this question can be opinionated, I would like to get some feedback on what techniques are being used on create fully offline app.

Is it always a custom implementation based on app needs?

Or instead of syncing in the old way matching and updating records, should the approach be taken from event standpoint.  Any persistence that is trigger from a page in the mobile app is considered an event.  If app is offline then the events just get stacked, when app comes back on online, the events are sent to the API.  An offset to the CQRS design.

I haven't really found anything more then very simple table level syncing which is great in simple world but not practical for what my structure is.

Comment: I've worked with https://realm.io/ which could be what you need.

Comment: @FelixD.thanks I will look into them.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync

Comment: @SébastienPertus I started reading through this and i looks like exactly what I am looking for with a good flexibility.  To allow for my current SQL Server DB.

Comment: @SébastienPertus Do you have plans or pre-release verion for .netcore 3.  I am running aspnetcore 3, but i looks like some of the dependencies are for Dotmim.Sync.Web.Server are for aspnetcore 2.2

Comment: @ChampChris It's actually coded on top of .Net Standard 2.0, so it's working on .Net Core 2+
The tests project is running on .Net Core 3.1

Comment: @SébastienPertus ok great thanks.  I haven't a chance to pull in the nuget i was just looking at the dependencies.  and reviewing the documentation.  Im going to review the examples shortly

Comment: @SébastienPertus Does it supports Xamarin iOS project. I tried to wrap Dotmim Sync in .net Standard 2.2/2.0 lib. Till here it all works. Once I add the reference in Xaamrin IOS project while building the app its throws error. - Error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while processing references of 'SMARTS.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (MT2001) . Please help.

Comment: @KumarAditya you might get a quicker response if ask your question on the github repo https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync

Comment: I haven't the run the Xamarin.iOS but I run the Xamarin.Android all the time with the Dotmim libraries installed no issues with the dependencies.  I will try the iOS version just to see if i get the same issue